# Trouble displaying Result of random number function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble displaying the output of the variable 'uitkomst', as you meight see, I want to act on the output of the random number function.

Javascript (canvas.js):

```
    var uitkomst = function dobbel()
{
return Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
}

function dobbelresultaat()
{
  if (uitkomst() ==1) 
{
oog5();
}
  if (uitkomst() ==2) 
{
oog2(),oog5();
}
  if (uitkomst() ==3) 
{
oog1(),oog5(), oog9();
}

  if (uitkomst() ==4) 
{
oog1(),oog2(),oog4(),oog5();
}

  if (uitkomst() ==5) 
{
oog1(),oog3(),oog5(),oog7(),oog9();
}

  if (uitkomst() ==6) 
{
oog1(),oog2(),oog3(),oog4(),oog5(),oog6();
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
  <title>Tekenprogrammatje</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="canvas.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <article>
      <button id="Gooi dobbelsteen" onClick="dobbel()">dobbel</button>
      <button id="resultaat" onClick="dobbelresultaat()">Laat uitkomst zien</button>
      <button id="tekeningweghalen" onClick="wisTekening(), wisTekening2()">Wissen</button>
    </article>
    <br>
  </div>
  <canvas id='figuur1' width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Example of oog1() etc:

```
function oog8()
{
var canvas =document.getElementById("figuur1");
var pen =canvas.getContext("2d");
pen.beginPath();
pen.strokeStyle="Maroon";
pen.arc(300,200,30,0,2*Math.PI);
pen.stroke();
pen.fillStyle="Maroon";
pen.fill();
canvas.style.position="absolute";
canvas.style.left="0px";
canvas.style.right="0px";
canvas.style.top="0px";
canvas.style.bottom="0px";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions. For example using the snippet editor to have the code here is useful

Comment: What is oog1() etc doing? and why do you not use `uitkomst() ` and a switch? Also you need to return the value and not return window.alert();

Comment: oog1() etc are displaying circles of a dice using canvas, the random number function imitates throwing a dice. The window.alert was to see if I get a result at all, which is not working for me at the moment. (I'm just a rookie to javascript)

Comment: Start with [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) - like this: `switch (uitkomst()) {
  case 1: oog5(); break;
  case 2: oog2(); oog5(); break;` and so on

Comment: My school only allows me to use the if else function, I edited my main post, I corrected the return.

Comment: if (uitkomst() ==1) ... You need the brackets. Also you cannot call dobbel from onclick. You need to store uitkomst() since that is the name of the function.

Comment: I'll explain what the script intends to do:
If the user clicks on the first button, it needs to "Roll the dice"
If the user clicks on the second button, it needs to display the circles depending on the number the dice rolled on.

Comment: I must have that button, that was part of the assignment.

I edited the js, it displays all oog()'s except for oog8() now permanently.

Comment: then you need to store the uitkomst in a global variable

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: Also change the commas between the oog to semicolons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the var and function

```
var uitkomst = 0; // global variable
function dobbel() {
  uitkomst = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
}
```

Change the commas to semicolons and add else

```
function dobbelresultaat() {
  if (uitkomst == 1) { // testing the global var uitkomst now 
    oog5();
  }
  else if (uitkomst == 2) {
    oog2(); oog5();
  }
```

Add an `<html>` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
```

Make sure the buttons do not submit the page

```
<button type="button" ....
```

Comment: You already helped me with the last answer you gave, the script finally works, just needed to declare the variable correctly, I had been working on this for 7 hours so I guess I just couldn't see what I was doing wrong anymore.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Geen dank :) Ik hoop je krijg een goede uitkomst ;)